# How to make web application render everything in a 90 degree rotated viewport?

Tags: html, css, layout, browser, css-transforms

I have a system where I use a Chromecast to show a web application written in React, on a monitor.

Now, we need to show this web application on a display that is mounted with a 90 degree rotation (portrait mode). If I was just using a PC as source, it would be easy to rotate the video output and the Chrome browser would just have a 1080x1920 viewport for rendering the website.

But since the Chromecast cannot rotate its output, I need to make the web application rotate all content to make it work on the rotated monitor.

The web app is currently written in a way that all element sizes are based on values relative to viewport height/width (`vh` units), so the content will automatically scale when shown in on different screens. This also causes the issues, explained below.

I tried making the CSS below, but it does not really work as expected, as it seems to just be rotating the content but not rendering it in a rotated viewport (I hope you understand what I mean).

```css
body {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

The result was that it rotated my 1920x1080 content so it would take up 1080x1920 in a viewport that was still 1920x1080...

Is there any way to do this in an "easy way" similar to changing screen rotation of the OS, or should I really rewrite all CSS in order to support a 90 degree rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `width: 1080px;` to the `body`. I don't really know how to rotate the screen, so I'll just let you test it.

```
body {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 1080px; /* Alternatively 100vw (maybe) */
}
```